# "pre" and "post" remove Middleware not firing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, middleware

I have implemented two different ways to remove a user and not one of them fires the "pre" and "post" remove Middleware.

As I understand

Below are my two different implementations in my model file:

Method One:

```
var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

userSchema.pre('remove', function(next) {
    // 'this' is the client being removed. Provide callbacks here if you want
    // to be notified of the calls' result.
    //Vouchers.remove({user_id: this._id}).exec();
    console.log("pre test");
    next();
});

userSchema.post('remove', function(next) {
    // 'this' is the client being removed. Provide callbacks here if you want
    // to be notified of the calls' result.
    //Vouchers.remove({user_id: this._id}).exec();
    console.log("post test");
    next();
});

// Remove User
module.exports.removeUser = function(id, callback){
    var query = {_id: id};
    console.log('test');
    //User.remove(query, callback);
    User.find(query).remove(callback);

}
```

Method Two:

```
var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

userSchema.pre('remove', function(next) {
    // 'this' is the client being removed. Provide callbacks here if you want
    // to be notified of the calls' result.
    //Vouchers.remove({user_id: this._id}).exec();
    console.log("pre test");
    next();
});

userSchema.post('remove', function(next) {
    // 'this' is the client being removed. Provide callbacks here if you want
    // to be notified of the calls' result.
    //Vouchers.remove({user_id: this._id}).exec();
    console.log("post test");
    next();
});

// Remove User
module.exports.removeUser = function(id, callback){
    var query = {_id: id};
    console.log('test');
    User.remove(query, callback);
}
```

Answer (score 13):

This is how I got everything working:

```
// Remove User
module.exports.removeUser = function(id, callback){

    User.findById(id, function (err, doc) {
        if (err) {

        }

        doc.remove(callback);
    })
}

//Remove vouchers related to users
userSchema.pre('remove', function(next) {
    this.model('Voucher').remove({ user: this._id }, next);
});
```

Comment: how is this different from my answer?

Comment: Your answer did not help me at all. I can also point people to documentation and tell them to go figure it out themselves. I try to elaborate and explain what and why when I answer questions, thus I up-vote accordingly. I just find that anyone can skim through the documents and refer people.

Comment: @SiegfriedGrimbeek Though you don’t give an answer that describes how to make `Model.remove()` run the pre/post remove hooks nor do you explicitly state that hooks don’t run in that case. If you could explain why Mongoose can only run hooks on an instance, that’d be helpful.

Comment: the holy docs: `Model.remove() - This method sends a remove command directly to MongoDB, no Mongoose documents are involved. Because no Mongoose documents are involved, no middleware (hooks) are executed.`

In the above example, the doc was first found, and then removed.

Answer (score 11):

Anyone else searching for the same. deleteOne and deleteMany middlewares can be used with pre and post middlewares. Remove has been deprecated from the latest mongo release.

The code below got things working for me.

```
   ModelSchema.pre("deleteOne", { document: true }, function(next) {
      let id = this.getQuery()["_id"];
      mongoose.model("Model_two").deleteMany({ property: id }, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
          next(err);
        } else {
          next();
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: Amazing! I was in need of this getQuery stuff, the docs didn't help

Answer (score 9):

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html
Please refer to the documentation. By design the middleware hook for remove is not fired for Model.remove, only for ModelDocument.remove function.

Comment: Note: There is no query hook for remove(), only for documents. If you set a 'remove' hook, it will be fired when you call myDoc.remove(), not when you call MyModel.remove()

Comment: If this is by design, how can the design be changed?

Answer (score 6):

For anyone having the issue in future, check that you defined your hooks before calling `mongoose.model()`.

> #### Define Middleware Before Compiling Models
>
> Calling `pre()` or `post()` after [compiling a model](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html#compiling) does not work in Mongoose in general. For example, the below `pre('save')` middleware will not fire.
>
> ...

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#defining

Answer (score 1):

You need to add

```
{document:false,query:true}
```

parameter to `userSchema('remove',callback)` middleware for `Query.remove()`. It is also important to understand difference between query middleware and document middleware.

### Query middleware and Query.remove()

`UserSchema.pre('remove',callback)` will not be fired by default if it is a query middleware. As a solution

```
var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
//...
userSchema.pre('remove',{document:false,query:true}, callback);
//...
module.exports.removeUser = function(id, callback){
    User.remove(callback);
}
```

We pass `{document:false,query:true}` parameter to middleware.

```
User.remove(callback)//Query.remove()
```

will not return a document from database.It will execute a remove operation and it will not call `doc.remove()`. It will call `Query.remove()`.

### Document middleware and doc.remove()

> `userSchema.pre('remove',callback)` is registered as a *document middleware* **by default**.

The code snippet below will run smoothly without additional parameters.

```
var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
//...
userSchema.pre('remove', callback);
//...
module.exports.removeUser = function(id, callback){
    User.find(query).remove(callback);//doc.remove()
}
```

`userSchema.pre('remove',callback)` **will be fired** because `User.find(query)` returns a mongoose document from database and `User.find(query).remove(callback)` will call `doc.remove()`

Answer (score 0):

Only document middleware

```
// query document and delete
schema.findOne({ _id: id}).then((doc) => {
  doc.remove().then(() => {
    console.log(`it works!`)
  })
})
// schema
schema.pre('remove', { document: true, query: false }, function() {
  console.log('Removing doc!')
})
```

The delete was deprecated, try to use deleteOne instead.

Only query middleware. This will get called when you do `Model.deleteOne()` but not `doc.remove()`.

```
// delete from model
schema.deleteOne({ _id: id }).then((removed) => {
  console.log(`it works!`)
}
// schema
schema.pre('deleteOne', { query: true, document: false }, function() {
  let id = this.getQuery()['_id']
  console.log(`${id} was Removing!`)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using the exact functions that you're calling, eg `pre('save')` and `pre('updateOne')` do not get called for `model.findOneAndUpdate()`