# remove post doesn't triggered in mongoose , node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Here i want to delete list and referenced items.So i made post Hook in List schema.But the post doesn't triggered. So give me suggestions to do that.

In my List controller ..

```
List.findOne({_id:req.params.list_id},function(error,list){
        if(list){
       //     console.log("dsdas");
            List.remove(list,function(err){
                if(err)res.send("no");
                else res.send("yes");
            })
           //    res.json(list);
        }
        else console.log("no");
        })
```

In my **List** schema

```
listSchema.post('remove',function(lists){
   // console.log("dasdasd");
      if(lists){
        Item.remove({_list:lists.id},function(error,items){
            if(items)console.log("yes");
            else console.log("no");
        });
    }
    else{
        return ;
    }  
    })
```

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/34464916/1495902

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongoose - "pre" and "post" remove Middleware not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34464861/mongoose-pre-and-post-remove-middleware-not-firing)